# How to properly reference a class from a Collection and a direct Reference

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one

I have two Entities: Box and Link.
(Both inherit from _BaseClass, but I do not think that's relevant - it might be though....)

So a Box contains link1, link2, and a Collection of Links.

**_BaseEntity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class _BaseEntity implements Comparable<_BaseEntity> {
    @Expose //
    @Id //
    @GeneratedValue() //
    protected long id;

    public _BaseEntity() {}

    public long getID() {
        if (id == 0) return creationId;
        return id;
    }

    @Override public final int hashCode() {
        return (int) getID();
    }
    @Override public final boolean equals(final Object pObj) {
        if (pObj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != pObj.getClass()) return false;
        final _BaseEntity other = (_BaseEntity) pObj;
        return id == other.id;
    }
    @Override public int compareTo(final _BaseEntity arg0) {
        return (int) (getID() - arg0.getID());
    }
}
```

**Box:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PT_Box")
public class Box extends _BaseEntity {

    @Expose private String name;

    @Expose //
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent") //
    private Link link1;

    @Expose //
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent") //
    private Link link2;

    @Expose //
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent") //
    private final ArrayList<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Link:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PT_Link")
public class Link extends _BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") //
    private final Box parent; // dont expose for not looping!

    @Expose private String  name;
    @Expose private String  link;

    @Expose private Date    lastUpdate;
    @Expose private Date    nextUpdate;

}
```

**Problems:**

- The Links get messed up. 'link1' and 'link2' show the first element of 'link'.
- And vice versa: if I set 'link1', then the list 'links' will show it as first element.

**Suspicion:**

I am sure, that is due to the mappings

- Box: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
- Link: @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")

that they also link those links into the variables 'link1' and 'link2'.

**Question:**

So my question: **how to manage/annotate this properly?**

- Un-map 'link1' and 'link2' somehow?
- Annotate 'link1' and 'link2' as @Transient, so that the references only get set by the Link-side? (if that works at all...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect.

First of all, the hashCode and equals() methods should not use the generated ID. You should probably not have any equals or hashCode method. That's the safest way (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode)

Second, the collection must be of type List, not ArrayList.

Third: you need three different join columns( and thus three different parent fields) in the Link entity:

- one to know what box contains the link as its link1 (OneToOne, owner side of the OneToOne link1 association)
- one to know what box contains the link as its link2 (OneToOne, owner side of the OneToOne link2 association)
- one to know what box contains the link as one of the elements of its links list (ManyToOne, owner side of the OneToMany links association)

Comment: Cool, thanx for that answer. **First:** I know of the problems, and actually my implementations here is cut down, it has more to it, making sure there are no problems arising with persistence. (EclipseLink/Payara even causes problems without it.)

**Second:** Why must it be List, not ArrayList? I have seen that multiple times already, but so far, I never had any problems with using the specific Types (ArrayList, HashSeh, TreeSet etc).

**Third:** so I do need three separate Variables in Link, each annotated the way you wrote? Or is there a way I dont know of, to annotate the same variable?

Comment: 2. Because the JPA spec mandates it. And it mandates it because the JPA engine must be able to use its own collection implementations handling lazy loading. Programming to interfaces is a best practice anyway. 3. Yes, you need 3 separate variables, annotated the way I suggested.

Comment: Thanx again for your elaborations. Ill try that out and then select it as solution. A little 'but' on the side: `Programming to interfaces is a best practice anyway.` is not completely correct. `Accept parameters as generic as possible, return values as specific as possible` is the thing. Because I can always cast type->supertype without problems. supertype->type is dangerous. Plus, in some JVM implementations, calling the interface methods is slower than the implemented ones. In the case of JPAs custom Collection implementations, following your args, it's more like 'lazyness' on the JPA side.

Comment: Alright, that worked well in the end. Had to extend the CTOR and create a `@Transient Box parent;` and add a `@PostLoad` method, to set the parent to one of the three possibilities. But all in all, it worked just nicely. Thanx again.